# Diff two directories in linux then output any changed files to a new directory

Tags: linux, diff

What is the best way of getting the differences between two directories then outputting only what has changed to a third directory while still maintaining proper directory/file hierarchy?

diff gets me a list ( `diff -rq dir1 dir2` ):

```
 Files dir1/1/2/3/file.php and dir2/1/2/3/file.php differ
 Files dir1/2/1/1/file.html and dir2/2/1/1/file.html differ
 Files dir1/3/file.css and dir2/3/file.css differ
 Only in dir1/1/2/3/: file.xml
```

Is there a single command that will output:

```
 dir3/1/2/3/file.php 
 dir3/2/1/1/file.html
 dir3/3/file.css
 dir3/1/2/3/file.xml
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `diff` natively has an option for that.  Have you considered `awk` to modify the output results?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with awk. I'll look into it

Comment: What do you want in dir3? Diff output, or the entire file from dir1 or dir2? Also, if there was a file only in dir2, would it also go to dir3?

Comment: dir3 would be all files from dir1 that have changed from dir2. This would include files that are in dir1 but not dir2.